# Hotline to Freshchat Migration iOS Crash

Tags: ios, swift, freshdesk

I was using `Hotline` in my app and recently I moved to `Freshchat SDK`. I followed the exact steps available on https://support.freshchat.com/support/solutions/articles/229394-freshchat-ios-sdk-swift-3-integration

It works if I fresh install the app but it doesn't work if I keep the older version with `hotline` in my phone and install this new one with `Freshchat`.

Since I am a developer I can just do fresh install everytime. But I can't ask all of my app users to install the app again.

Comment: interesting how two apps can communicate until you have not provided any URI/keychain etc mechanism.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you trying to say @Gagan_iOS

Comment: by the way, did you try to install and run both apps on different phones?

Comment: Both app runs find individually. Only issue comes when I run new one on the older one which basically how the app's update works. @Gagan_iOS

Comment: ok.. does your previous build contains CoreData, SQlite etc? If Yes, then during update did you perform migration steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was `Freshchat`'s issue. I contacted their support team and they send me their hotfix build. I am just answering because there is no solution that I have fixed. 
Only thing I did was install `FreshchatSDK` from their branch

```
pod 'FreshchatSDK', :git => 'https://github.com/freshdesk/freshchat-ios', :branch => 'canary'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It was an SDK issue. We have fixed them in version [v1.0.2](https://github.com/freshdesk/freshchat-ios/releases/tag/v1.0.2).